# Is there a more efficient way to read this DataTable so I can write it to a CSV file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, csv

I'm looking at an old web app I wrote and it is taking about an hour to read 4500 records from a `DataTable` so it can write them to a CSV file. I feel there has to be some way to improve this.

Few things to note:

- The DataTable contains... 376 columns

  At least, I think that's what Excel's `NL` column converts to. I just looked up the column count now and had no idea there were so many. Our software vendor hasn't realized the value of dynamic sql statements for this process, so every software "upgrade" just keeps adding more columns rather than only selecting the ones needed.
- I cannot alter the SQL statement that generates the data
- Depending on the data type, the data needs to be formatted in a specific format
- Data does contains special characters, such as commas
- The slow part is reading the data. Getting the data from the SQL server and writing it to a CSV is fast.

Here's the code. Forgive the mess, I wrote it back when I didn't know what I was doing and when I still was working in VB

```
Function ReadDataTableForCSV(dt as DataTable)
    
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
    Dim dataTypes As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    
    ' Header Row
    For i as Integer = 0 to dt.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim col as DataColumn = dt.Columns(i)
    
        Dim t = col.DataType
        If t is GetType(Boolean) Then
            dataTypes.Add(i, 1)
        Else If t is GetType(Decimal) Then
            dataTypes.Add(i, 2)
        Else
            dataTypes.Add(i, 3)
        End If
    
        sb.Append(String.Format("""{0}""", col.ColumnName))
        sb.Append(Iif(i = dt.Columns.Count - 1, vbLf, ","))
    
    Next
    
    ' Items
    For Each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            Select dataTypes(i)
                Case 1
                sb.Append(String.Format("""{0}""", CInt(row(i))))
            Case 2
                sb.Append(String.Format("""{0}""", FormatNumber(row(i), 2, , , 0)))
            Case 3
                sb.Append(String.Format("""{0}""", row(i)))
            End Select
                    
            sb.Append(Iif(i = dt.Columns.Count - 1, vbLf, ","))
      Next
    Next
    
End Function
```

**Edit:** Removed code not related to the problem

Comment: First things first - there are two very separate sections of code here; reading from the data table, and writing to the disk. Which is slow? (I would *definitely* tidy up the file writing code, mind you. Simply `File.WriteAllText` would do it in a single call.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry I should have clarified that. The part reading from the DataTable is the slow part.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken before: there are obviously *three* separate sections of code - getting the DataTable (your call to GetMyDataTable), reading from it, and then writing. Is it definitely the reading from the datatable which is slow rather than creating it to start with?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's definitely the reading portion. Originally it wrote the DataTable directly to the file, and I could watch the file size grow as it built the file and know that's the part that is taking an hour or so. And thanks for the `WriteAllText()` method, I wasn't aware that existed :)

Comment: Since you can't change the query pulling the data out you may be out of luck trying to speed this up. An hour to pull 4500 records seems like an awfully long time.

Could you post the code that generates the datatable? Without seeing that piece there's not much we can do to help you out.

Comment: @Tim the code that generates the DataTable is fine. It runs in a few seconds. The part that is slow is reading the DataTable so it can be written to the CSV file

Comment: If you haven't already, it might be a good time to try a profile such as RedGate's ANTS Profile. It'd be helpful to post a screenshot of a profiler snapshot for the duration of this function. Breakpoint when the function starts, clear the profiler, breakpoint when the function stops, take a snapshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would rewrite it:

1. Allocate the stringbuilder memory up front.
2. Change the data types from a dictionary to a byte array and only use values 1 and 2; value 3 will now be 0, which will be the default for items in the array.
3. Use the Ordinal property from the column rather than a separate index.
4. Streamline the evaluations inside the loop for item and line separators.
5. Use Decimal.ToString instead of FormatNumber.
6. Remove iifs (these are probably optimized by the compiler, but I am still leery of them from the early VB days)

Here's the code:

```
Function ReadDataTableForCSV(dt As DataTable)

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(100000000)
    Dim dataTypes As Byte()

    ReDim dataTypes(dt.Columns.Count - 1)

    ' Header Row
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        If sb.Length <> 0 Then
            sb.Append(",")
        End If

        Select Case col.DataType.ToString
            Case "System.Boolean"
                dataTypes(col.Ordinal) = 1

            Case "System.Decimal"
                dataTypes(col.Ordinal) = 2

                ' Everything else defaults to 0

        End Select

        sb.Append("""").Append(col.ColumnName).Append("""")
    Next

    sb.AppendLine()
    ' or  sb.Append(vbLf)

    ' Items
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            If i <> 0 Then
                sb.Append(",")
            End If

            sb.Append("""")
            Select Case dataTypes(i)
                Case 1
                    If CBool(row(i)) Then
                        sb.Append("1")
                    Else
                        sb.Append("0")
                    End If

                Case 2
                    sb.Append(CDec(row(i)).ToString("F"))

                Case Else
                    sb.Append(row(i))

            End Select

            sb.Append("""")
        Next

        sb.AppendLine()
        ' or  sb.Append(vbLf)
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Its almost time for me to head home today but I am very interested in giving your suggestions a try tomorrow and seeing if it runs any faster. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea which one of your suggestions cut back on the execution time, but it went from taking almost an hour down to less than a minute! I was unable to allocate the memory up front for the StringBuilder, however apparently that wasn't the big issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Filehelpers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filehelpers/). It's very fast, handles quoted fields, and simplifies both reading and writing delimited and fixed-width files.

A walkthrough can be found on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/filehelpers.aspx).

If you read records from the database into strongly typed classes using an ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) then you can hand the array of strongly typed classes from the ORM, which would be decorated with the DelimitedRecord and FieldConverter attributes, to the Filehelpers Engine.

The download link on Sourceforge and the Filehelpers website is a bit old. It works, but I'd recommend pulling the latest source from Sourceforge.

**EDIT**

Nothing stands out as being the one single performance hit. Maybe it's a collection of small hits? Give this a shot.

- Rather than populate and enumerate a DataTable, enumerate the DataReader directly. Less boxing.
- If you're on the latest version of VB.NET, use the ternary IF rather than IIF. It's type safe.
- Fewer String.Formats.
- Fewer dictionary lookups. I imaging a type check is faster than a dictionary lookup. Maybe someone can speak to this?
- Fewer implicit type conversions.

This is a shot in the dark rewrite. :)

```
Function ReadDataTableForCSV(dr As SqlDataReader) As String
    Dim fieldCount As Integer = dr.FieldCount
    Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

    ' Header Row
    For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount - 1
        sb.AppendFormat("""{0}""", dr.GetName(i))
        sb.Append(If(i = fieldCount - 1, vbLf, ","))
    Next

    ' Items
    While dr.Read()
        For i As Integer = 0 To fieldCount - 1
            Dim t As Type = dr.GetFieldType(i)

            sb.Append("""") 'quoted cell
            If t Is GetType(Boolean) Then
                sb.Append(If(dr.GetBoolean(i), "1", "0"))
            ElseIf t Is GetType(Decimal) Then
                sb.Append(dr.GetDecimal(i).ToString("#.##"))
            Else
                sb.Append(dr(i))
            End If
            sb.Append("""") 'quoted cell

            sb.Append(If(i = fieldCount - 1, vbLf, ","))
        Next
    End While

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: I see you used the ASP.NET tag. If my memory serves me well, you can tell Filehelpers to write straight to the ResponseStream rather than write to a file. The user would have no idea that the file they're downloading is being generated AS it's downloaded.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear in my question. The slow part is reading the `DataTable`, not writing the CSV file.

Comment: I see. You also mentioned that there are 370+ columns, which would translate into an unreasonably large class. My answer does not fit your needs. :)

Comment: I edited my answer with a shot in the dark rewrite. It removes the intermediate DataTable. There's less implicit type conversion. The decimal formatting might not be correct.

Comment: Thanks :) I originally did the type check in the loop, and moved it to a dictionary to see if it would run any faster (it doesn't). The original version also had no `string.formats` (it was all stuff like `"""" + row(i) + """"`). I will see how it runs using a DataReader instead of a DataTable, and try using  the `GetBoolean()` and `GetDecimal()` instead of using implicit type conversions.

Comment: Something I left out, you might need to check for DBNull.Value. GetBoolean and GetDecimal aren't null safe.

Comment: It actually took longer to run with those changes. I pretty much copied/pasted what you had. I think doing the type checking in the loop is worse on performance, because its what I originally had and both time out in an hour while if I use a dictionary to store the types it runs in about 50 minutes. I still want to try once more using a DataReader instead of a DataTable, although I don't have high hopes for that.

Answer (score 0):

if getting the datatable is the bottleneck and you cannot alter the sql statement and the results are returned as datatable, there is not much that can be done.

if you can control how the results are returned then return an ienumerable. where T is either a POCO or IDataRecord, something and use deferred execution. this will keep memory consumption low as you will only load the record as you consume it.

reading the data may look like this

```
while(reader.Reader())
{
    yield return reader; // or reader.ConvertRecordToObject<T>(); //extension method
}
```

then you can `foreach` the results to write out to a csvfile

```
foreach(var record in GetEnumerationOfRecords())
{
     WriteToCsv(record);
}
```

this still leaves the issue of the sql statement, which is most likely causing the bulk of the performance problem, but you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: The problem is definitely not the SQL statement. I have tested a few different ways and the performance problem is in reading the data table. If I comment out the foreach section which loops through the data table and writes the results to the StringBuilder, it runs in a few seconds. My problem is not memory consumption either. It is the performance - a file should not take an hour to generate.

Comment: then, if the option exists, don't return a datatable. i would still recommend using deferred execution.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried using a DataReader instead of a DataTable and it didn't change the execution time

Comment: have you profiled the code so you know exactly where your bottleneck is?

Comment: I haven't profiled it, but I know the slowdown is in the loop that reads the DataTable and writes it to the StringBuilder

Comment: a profiler will pinpoint exactly where the bottleneck is. JetBrains `dotTrace` and Ants `Profiler` are both excellent tools.